# Python3 web scraping, csv output showing TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a webpage and storing its output to a CSV file. It works ok if I just output the results on the terminal but when I try to f.write() to a CSV file it gives an error TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Example code:

```
desc = []
for desc_tag in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "card-body"}):
desc.append(desc_tag.text)
```

if I do print(desc) it gives the desired output on my terminal, but when I do

```
f.write(srcs + ", " + titles + ", " + desc + ", " + urls + "\n")
```

I get the TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

srcs, titles, desc, URLs they are all same just for ease of it I only added the desc but the syntax for all is the same as my example code above.

my code for creating CSV/and output

```
out_filename = "bookmarks_design.csv"
headers = "image,title,description,link \n"
f = open(out_filename, "w")
f.write(headers)
```

Any pointers as to how I can fix this?
Thanks

Comment: What are the values of `srcs`, `titles`, `desc` and `urls`? Can you show the output of `print(srcs)` for example?

Comment: print(titles) 

['Dixon', 'Regan, 'Tinypng', 'Coddrops', 'Creative Portfolios', 'AI']

Comment: I even tried 
# Converting string to list
bd_titles = titles.strip('][').split(', ')
but I get an error
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Those are lists. You to place `f.write` inside a loop.

Comment: `titles` is not a string that has `]`, `[` and `,`. It is a list of strings. You can access each string using its index as `titles[0]`, `titles[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`srcs`, `titles`, `desc` and `urls` **are lists**. To write their content to a file (using `f.write`), you need a loop:

```
for i in range(len(srcs)):
    f.write(srcs[i] + ", " + titles[i] + ", " + desc[i] + ", " + urls[i] + "\n")
```